# How to show specific table structure in a Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I forgot my cPanel credentials so that now i need to confirm about some table fields i.e data types etc so that I want to connect with that cPanel i am using Laravel 4.2 and have no env file. Can anybody can give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: Do I understand correctly. You lost your cPanel instance *database credentials* ? If so you should have them in app/config/database.php folder. Look also for specific environment folder and database.php file in it.

Comment: yes, there was an instance like this.

'database'  => 'ummercial_db',
   'username'  => 'ummercial_user',
   'password'  => 'PHGWXLIXq',

but how can i get the specific table structure? or need to add new table in this db?

Comment: Creating and modifying tables is simple using Laravel migrations. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations For easy access to your database, I would recommend truning on SSH access in CPanel and accessing database through SSH tunnel with MySQL client of your choice.